# Mediation Analysis with Interaction of Mediators

Tags: interaction, mediation, lavaan

I am not an expert in mediation analysis or structural equation modelling. I looked in the standard reference for mediation analysis (i.e., Hayes) and searched the forum and internet a bit and could not find an answer to my question.

Is it possible to run a mediation model in lavaan in which I test the assumption that two causally unrelated mediators AND their interplay (= interaction) contribute as indirect effects?

My very naive approach would be to run a parallel mediation model with three mediators consisting of mediator 1, mediator 2, and mediator 3 = mediator 1 x mediator 2 (= interaction; I would center mediator variables to reduce multicollinearity issues).

Is this a valid approach? Thank you for a hint!

Marc